# ¿Como intercambiar bases de datos con un select?

Tags: php, html, mysql, cron

¡Hola! , Resulta que necesito guardar registros por año en cada bases de datos por ej : db_2022,db_2023 , y que se creen automaticamente, tal vez tenga que hacerlo con un cron lo automatico , y de esta forma que el usuario con un select pueda escoger el año deseado, y que se desplieguen los registros de ese año por el cambio de bases de datos de db_2022 a db_2023 , y de esta forma reiniciar la tabla que el id comienze nuevamente a 1(soy consciente que tal vez no sea la manera y que puedo hacer algo mas facil con una filtracion de fecha con una condicion sql creando un campo para fecha en pero resulta que me estan pidiendo esto :/  ) si hay alguna otra manera de producir esto me ayudarían muchisimo!

Codigo que probe para poder producir en pequeñas proporciones esto :

```html
<?php
$db = new Mysqli('localhost', 'root', ' ', 'database'); //make connection
$db->query('CREATE DATABASE `db' . date('Y') . '`'); // Crear base de datos
$db->select_db('db' . date('Y')); // Seleccionar nueva base de datos
$db->query(file_get_contents('cambio.sql')); // Importar la estructura sql limpia para cada base de datos
```

```html
select name="dbName">
   <?php
     for ($year = 2022; $year < date('Y') + 1; $year++) {
        echo '<option value="db' . $year . '">' . $year . '</option>';
     }
    ?>
 </option>
```

Y el ultimo es en torno a seleccion de año y cambio de año , (intercambio base de datos), me recomendaron usar un preg_match('/^db20[0-9]{2}$/', $name) por ejemplo, De antemano Muchas Gracias!

Comment: ¿Qué ganan al hacer eso? ¿Es posible que necesiten consultar los últimos n años?

Comment: @Sal Al parecer quieren lograr que los registros de id de todos los años sucesivos no sea alto y que por eso se reinicie nuevamente a 1 el id para que cada año no sea tan elevado el id al parecer y que se resetee cada año

Comment: Si lo único que quieres es un id bajo por año, entonces bastaría con añadir un id  manualmente en cada registro. Cada vez que se añada un registro compruebas el último id asignado para el año seleccionado y le sumas 1. Con eso te evitas todo esto de múltiples bases de datos. PD. No deberíamos dejar que los clientes nos digan como hacer las cosas, sino que digan que es lo que quieren conseguir

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema de que sea alto? Si es un problema de presentación no es necesario propagarlo a la persistencia. Internamente podemos manejar los ids a conveniencia, te dejo [un ejemplo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/WvS7drKGaTH1txSHxBt82/0).

Comment: En lugar de crear una nueva base de datos, puedes asignar prefijos por año a cada tabla `db2021_movimientos`, `db2022_movimientos`, etc. Así puedes tener todo en la misma base de datos, creando otra tabla donde guardes los años creados y obtenerlos de ahí para seleccionar sobre cuál se va a trabajar. Aunque coincido en las complicaciones que van a resultar de esto.

Comment: @Triby Claro!, eso estaba mencionando, ponerle el prefijo con esta sentencia : $db->query('CREATE DATABASE `db' . date('Y') . '`'); // Crear base de datos
 Y hacer un cron para que lo cree cada año hay me lo estaria tomando ,pero es mejor hacer una filtracion por busqueda de fecha es mas recomendable  no ?

Comment: No, una cosa es crear una nueva base de datos y otra, crear tablas con nombres diferentes dentro de la misma base de datos. Y no me fiaría de un cron, prefiero poner un botón para que el administrador agregue nuevos periodos.

Comment: @Triby Aaaah comprendo , y en temas de seleccion de tablas como podría producirlo , ya que  me falta hacer tambien validaciones como por ejemplo no agregar registros nuevos  del año pasado!De antemano Gracias por tu aporte!

Answer (score 0):

Una tabla por año es mala idea.
Puedes controlar la secuencia de id por año con ayuda de una tabla auxiliar (ej. `ids`) controlada desde un disparador:

```
CREATE TABLE ids( 
  anio INT PRIMARY KEY
, id INT 
);

CREATE TRIGGER todosLosAnios_bi BEFORE INSERT ON todosLosAnios
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO ids VALUES( NEW.anio, @id:=1 )
    ON DUPLICATE KEY
      UPDATE id = @id:=id+1;
  SET NEW.id = @id;
END
```

Así cada vez que insertes un registro, si es un año nuevo su id iniciará en 1 y los registros subsecuentes se incrementarán.

[Aquí un fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bYGokHDpcPQUbzZBDBXAA9/0) donde lo puedes ver funcionando con datos de ejemplo.